# Change Glyphicon margin/padding in bootstrap badge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a glyphicon in a badge, and I would like to have the glyphicon have a smaller font-size than the text. This works fine, but now the glyphicon is not centered vertically in the badge.

When I try and give it a margin-bottom or padding-bottom it goes and adds this to the entire badge, and not just the glyphicon element.

Here is the .css class I'm using:

```
.glyphicon-test3 {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <span id="test" class="badge">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-test3"></span>

    Small icon with padding

  </span>
</div>
```

I've made a PLNKR which shows the effect in it's full glory: http://plnkr.co/edit/VBIeaffmFujY2qcdPcVI

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the HTML in the question as well, so that the issue is reproducible.

Comment: Yep - forgot to put it in... i've put it in there now... it is also in the plnkr btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `top:-1px` and overwrite the existing `top: 1px` to `.glyphicon` selector

```
.glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px; <<<This causing the problem
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

So

```
.glyphicon-test3 {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 6px;
  line-height: 2;
  top: -1px; <<<Here
}
```

Note: I remove the padding and add height

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3q227gt/)

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is the "top: 1px" that the glyphicon class specifies. It's a little better if you override that as well (to 0, or even better at -1). You may also want to play around with the line-height (also 1 as it stands).

Answer (score 0):

in my css, this worked for me. GL

```
.glyphicons::before {
    padding: 0px;
}
```